# Question about increasing and decreasing functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential

[image: diagram]

Hi, I was studying the mean value theorem and increasing and decreasing functions. This question came to my mind.
Can we say that $f$ increases on $[a,b]$?

Comment: Yes, this function is increasing.

Comment: Yes.  That is, the function does not have to be continuous to be either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To flesh out the comments while not aiming for maximum generality: If $X$ is a set of real numbers, and if $f$ is a real-valued function on $X$, we say $f$ is (*strictly*) *increasing* (on $X$) if $x_{1} < x_{2}$ implies $f(x_{1} < f(x_{2})$ for all $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ in $X$.

That is, "increasing functions preserve inequalities": Applying an increasing function to an inequality gives a new inequality of the same sign.

Notes:

- The term *non-decreasing* is similar, and means $x_{1} < x_{2}$ implies $f(x_{1} \leq f(x_{2})$. A strictly increasing function is non-decreasing. The term *increasing* may mean either *non-decreasing* or *strictly increasing* depending on the author. Authors often specify their convention early in the book. (Analogous remarks apply to the terms "decreasing", "non-increasing", and "strictly decreasing".)
- There is a well-known sufficient criterion in calculus for a function *defined on an interval* to be strictly increasing: Its derivative is positive everywhere. (Idea of proof: With the preceding notation, apply the mean value theorem to $f$ on $[x_{1}, x_{2}]$.)
- The well-known sufficient criterion is not necessary: $f(x) = x^{3}$ is strictly increasing, though $f'(0) = 0$. A strictly increasing differentiable function can have infinitely many critical points. In fact, the set of critical points can be an [arbitrary closed set with empty interior](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4146802). This point is often misunderstood.
- The well-known sufficient condition does not apply if the domain is not an interval. For example, $f(x) = -1/x$, defined on the set $X$ of non-zero real numbers (an interval with one point removed), has $f'(x) = 1/x^{2} < 0$ everywhere in its domain, but is not increasing: For example, $-1 < 1$, but $f(-1) = 1 > -1 = f(1)$.
- *Monotone* functions (which are non-decreasing or non-increasing) are among the nicest functions when we start digging into the theory underlying calculus. Particularly, a monotone function has one-sided limits at each interior point of its domain, whether or not the function is continuous there.